# Windows, OpenVPN: использовать только протокол IPv6

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn, ipv6

Имеется Windows 10 с IPv4 (провайдер IPv6 не умеет и чуда не случится) + VDS с IPv4 and IPv6.
На VDS поднят OpenVPN по IPv4, и он раздает две локалки IPv4 and IPv6. Обе локалки натятся на VDS. Все работает.. (IPv6 и IPv4 сайты открываются)
Но при использование интернета идет соединение по IPv4, и только если домен only IPv6 идет соединение по IPv6.
Возможно каким либо образом сделать так, что бы использовался протокол только IPv6?
Пытался нагуглить и что то ничего не нашел.. была идея вроде DNS сервера который резолвит только IPv6 адреса, но такого тоже не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего, OpenVPN создает виртуальную сеть, и является софтварным роутером сам по себе. Чтобы передавать весь трафик через себе, он ставит приоритет себе для всех IP адресов. Данная конфигурация отправляется сервером OpenVPN клиенту, т.е. роутер на вашей VDS говорит, что у него есть путь ко всему интернету.

Для переопределения данного поведения есть команда `route-nopull` , и команды `route` и `route-ipv6` для IPv4 и IPv6 соответственно. Для того, чтобы перенаправить только IPv6 трафик вам нужно добавить следущие строки в конфигурацию клиента:

`route-nopull
route-ipv6 ::/128`

`route-ipv6` принимает под-сеть как свой параметр, трафик из который будет перенаправлен OpenVPN серверу.
Так же есть возможность перенаправлять IPv4 трафик: `route 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255`.
[Более подробно можно прочитать здесь](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway)

При этом требуется отключить весь IPv4 трафик в вне, это можно сделать как на серверной стороне так и на клиенте:

- Для сервера, если вы используете Linux, можете заблокировать IPv4 средствами iptables
- Для клиента, возможно создать еще одно подключение через OpenVPN, отключив у него поддержку IPv6, и отключив весь перенаправляемый трафик средствами сервера.( Т.е. клиент будет пробовать отправить пакеты серверу, но он не будет ему отвечать )
- Для конфига, route принимает третьим параметром gateway - то, через что будут направляться пакеты. Никто не мешает написать туда IP адрес 0.0.0.1, что является черной дырой: `route 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.1`, из-за чего весь IPv4 трафик будет перенаправлен в никуда.

Если Вы используете Debian-подобную ОС, для отключения перенаправления IPv4 трафика Вы можете отредактировать файл `/etc/sysctl.conf`, и закоментировать net.ipv4.ip_forward , если другим пользователям так же не нужен IPv4

Данные способы будут работать только если IPv6 уже был настроен на сервере, т.к. это требует дополнительной конфигурации сервера.

Comment: Агонь! Огромное спасибо за столь развернутый ответ! P.S. Пришлось включить обратно IPv4, что бы написать этот ответ((

Comment: @Firsim какой из вариантов сработал для вас ? Я просто не пробовал вариант с blackhole gateway

Comment: Я воспользовался отключением "net.ipv4.ip_forward", но.. Винда упорно пытается с сайтами все равно по IPv4 коннектится, если существует в dns ответе только IPv6 тогда все ок, в противном случае сайт грузится минуты через 3. Вообщем странно эта приоритезация трафика работает по RFC..

Comment: @Firsim https://superuser.com/questions/436574/ipv4-vs-ipv6-priority-in-windows-7 - с гугл переводчиком, но думаю поможет. Можете открыть новый вопрос, если желаете перевести данную статью на Русский. Хотя вам всё, да наоборот, но думаю по аналогии сможете составить решение. Так же рекомендую посмотреть второй ответ, где есть файл прям для Вас.

Comment: Я думаю врятли получится, т.к. по умолчанию IPv6 в приоритете, вроде согласно RFC какой то там. Есть предположение, что решением проблемы будет DNS сервер который возвращает только IPv6 адрес, и , допустим, если его нет то тогда IPv4..